# Update Android Studio 3.0, error Sync Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I just install from zero Android Studio 3 and clone my project which doesn't use Android Studio 3 before. I tried to compile but gradle couldn't sync correctly.

I'm using gradle 4.3 because I search my problem on other post, but couldn't find how to fix. This is my gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.1.1"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And app/gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InnerclassSeparator'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fr.laway.dev.laway"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(path: ':laway_data', configuration: 'default')
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:1.5.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Finally, my errors :

[image]

Is something missing in my gradle file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it's related but I just update my realm library :

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.1.1"
```

This was enough for finish to compile and remove all errors. Gradle still is very mysterious for me x)

Answer (score 0):

From the error, gradle complaining this:

> android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android plugin. Please use
>   'annotationProcessor' configuration instead.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#annotationProcessor_config):

> **Use the annotation processor dependency configuration**
>
> In previous versions of the plugin, dependencies on the compile classpath were automatically added to the processor classpath. That is, you could add an annotation processor to the compile classpath and it would work as expected. However, this causes a significant impact to performance by adding a large number of unnecessary dependencies to the processor.
>
> When using the Android plugin 3.0.0, you must add annotation processors to the processor classpath using the annotationProcessor dependency configuration, as shown below:
>
> ```
>    dependencies {   
>        ...   
>        annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:<version-number>'       
>    }
> ```

You need to using annotationProcessor in your **laway_data** module `build.gradle`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what should i do with :

`dependencies {   
       ...   
       annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:<version-number>'       
   }`